# Atmel UC3 - how to get the serial number?

Tags: atmel, atmel-uc3

Each Atmel UC3 apparently has a unique serial number. Does anyone know how I retrieve it in software?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&p=922774&sid=8ce72b4a3a0697eaafed1ec7413c3bd3#922774

Even better: I wrote to Atmel tech support (which I should have done in the first place?) and got this reply:

The serial number is defined by a 120-bit data located at address 0x80800204-0x80800212 for UC3A. For each chip, the serial number is unique.

Here is an example:

```
volatile unsigned int* id_data = 0x80800204;
unsigned int ID_get[4];
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
   ID_get[i] = *id_data++;
```